# Can't retrieve some comments from Youtube video by CommentThreads:list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Please, help with Youtube API. CommentThreads:list doesn't give all TopLevelComments. I find several missing CommentID.

Example: comments correctly opens by URL:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hySk1m57PAQ&lc=z12jjlsjrlmsgp4lu23rhxbgmrenxl5py04
```

, 
but throw API function this commentID return no data:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?maxResults=99&alt=json&part=id%2Csnippet&key=<...key...>&textFormat=plainText&id=z12jjlsjrlmsgp4lu23rhxbgmrenxl5py04
```

What wrong this it? How can I get this comment?

Comment: I've tested you example, it initially didn't load to a comment. Where you able to get this commentID from the commentThreads->list?